# How can I use the Search Field Control in iOS and Mac?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I want to use and develop a dictionary application for iOS and Mac, but I don't know how to use the Cocoa search field control .
If there is sample code for that, please guide me there.
If there is documentation for search field control, please guide me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about search field here: [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SearchFields/Articles/AddingSearchField.html)

And tutorial how to implement and validate the Search Field here: [Tutorial](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1578733&seqNum=7)